# Change limit of sql without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I know sort of the same question has been asked before, but whatever I read and tried I just can't get my code to work.. I'm still sort of a noob and I have the feeling I'm doing it all wrong

So, right now I have a limit of 10. I want the limit to be 50 when I click the button 'view more', without refreshing the page.

This is my html:

```
    <?php
    require_once 'php/connection.php'; 
    include 'includes/head.php';
    ?>

    <body>
        <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>

        <section class="wrapper" id="projectshow">

           <?php

            $limit = '10';

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM expodetails order by rating desc LIMIT $limit");
            $counter = 1;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $projectname = $row['projectname'];

            ?>
            <article class="project-wrapper">
                <div class="project">
                <h3><?php echo "$projectname"; ?></h3>
            </article>

           <?php
                }
            ?>

        <a href="#" class="submit viewmore" onclick="bekijkmeer('a');">View more</a>
        </section>

        </body>
```

This is my file named ajax.js:

```
    function check(){

    var xmlHttp;
      try
        {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      catch (e)
        {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
          {
          xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          }
        catch (e)
          {
          try
            {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
          catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
          }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

    function bekijkmeer(x)
     { 
     var xmlHttp = check();




    xmlHttp.open("GET","/expoproject/php/changelimit.php?appeltje="+x+"",true);

              xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                {
                document.getElementById('topchange').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                }
              } 
            xmlHttp.send(null);
          }
```

And this is my file named changelimit.php:

```
<?php

            $limit = '50';

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM expodetails order by rating desc LIMIT $limit");
            $counter = 1;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $projectname = $row['projectname'];

            ?>
            <article class="project-wrapper">
                <div class="project">
                <h3><?php echo "$projectname"; ?></h3>
            </article>

           <?php
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: What is it doing now?  Are you getting an error?  Side note, mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should look into mysqli or PDO, with prepared statements.

Comment: There is no more pure javascript if not in Node.js. JQuery is your friend, really. Otherwise, your code seems alright.

Comment: It is working, but the page is still refreshing. Do you know of any way to avoid that?

Comment: I found the solution! Turns out I still had a '#' in my href, I replaced it with 'javascript:void(0)'